# How to add small icons beside VS Project Tree Items?

Tags: c#, wpf, vspackage, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-sdk

i am creating a VSPackage, i want to add small icon beside VS Project items, looks like in the attached image.
please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is available to Source Control packages.  You need to implement the [`IVsSccGlyphs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSccGlyphs.aspx) interface and have the  to return the list of available images.

You can also read more about how the status is calculated by Visual Studio by reading the documentation for the [`GetSccGlyph`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssccmanager2.getsccglyph.aspx) methods.